# Error #1063: Argument count mismatch - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, jquery-animate, adobe

I have a very simple animation i want to make but am stuck with these errors

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on ReverseCirculation_Complete_Graham_1_ActionScript3_fla::MainTimeline/Play(). Expected 0, got 1.
```

The idea is an animation will be paused, then clicked on "play" button to start with the ability to stop or pause the animation before clicking "Next" to preview the continued animation.

My code looks like this:

```
//imports needed
stop();

import flash.display.MovieClip; 
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

Play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Play);
Stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Stop);
Next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Next);

function Play()
{
blue1_mc.play();
red_mc.play();
green_mc.play();
}

function Stop()
{
blue1_mc.stop();
red_mc.stop();
green_mc.stop();
}

function Next(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Many thanks
Graham

Comment: You added the `event:MouseEvent` parameter to your `Next()` function. This parameter also needs to exist for your other 2 functions. That's what the error is trying to tell you. It's trying to call the `Play` method and pass it an argument, but because you defined that the method does not accept parameters: Error.

Comment: i see.... I needed the NEXT button to play the next scene on the stage (hence the gotoandstop), i have two other buttons which play animations on the stage.. not really sure what i can change tbh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AS3, when you define a function like so:

```
function Play()
```

You are telling it that there are no parameters/arguments for this function.  Unlike similar ECMAScript based languages such as JavaScript, if you end up passing a parameter - for example doing `Play("Hello")` - it will throw an error.

When you setup a event handler, like you do here:

```
Play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Play);
```

That event when triggered calls the function specified - `Play` - and passes it a `MouseEvent` object that describes the event (such as the object clicked, the mouse position etc.)

Since you've define the Play function to accept no arguments, you get the error saying there's an unexpected argument.  (same for the Stop function).

To remedy the issue, you can do 1 of these two things:

1. Add a MouseEvent argument to the function:

   ```
   function Play(event:MouseEvent){
   ```
2. Add a MouseEvent argument, but make it *optional*:

   ```
   function Play(event:MouseEvent = null){
   ```

The second option, means that you can still simply call `Play()` without passing it an argument.

Comment: +1 your a star! - turned out it was the MouseEvent functions were missing from the Play and stop buttons. Did not even think of them.  Thank you @BadFeelingAboutThis